# Is the following Hadith which says prophets would never get decomposed true or false?

Tags: quran, hadith, hadith-interpretation, death

I cam across this [Hadith - Chapters Regarding Funerals - Sunan Ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1289870)

> for Allah has forbidden the earth to consume the bodies of the Prophets

Which is classified as Da'if.

And in [Earth Does Not Consume Prophet's Body - Islamhelpline](http://islamhelpline.net/node/2771)

> The above **authentic** hadith specifically mentions that the earth does not consume ....

I would like to ask if this narration is true or false because I was about to write an article on it. Is there any hint from Quran?

Comment: Answering with "True" or "False" is difficult as neither you nor me nor anybody alive have heard the hadith. We can only give a qualification which can be right but could also be wrong, as we have no witnesses. Scholars have qualified ahadith and narrators according some rules, but this doesn't automatically imply that a hadith which has been qualified as *sane* by them was truly a saying of our Prophet (Peace be upon him) nor will this imply that a hadith qualified as *weak* was not. Of course when we have some kind of tawatur the degree of truth might get higher! We have no 100% certainty!

Answer (score 1):

This hadith is saheh "ibn heban" said it is saheh. ﻿

- مِن أفضلِ أيَّامِكم يومُ الجمعةِ ، فيهِ خُلقَ آدمُ وفيهِ قبضَ وفيهِ النَّفخةُ وفيهِ الصَّعقةُ فأكثِروا عليَّ مِن الصَّلاةِ فيهِ فإنَّ صلاتَكم معروضةٌ عليَّ ، قالوا : يا رسولَ اللَّهِ وَكيفَ تُعرضُ علَيكَ صلاتُنا وقد أرِمتَ ؟ يعني وقد بليتَ قال : إنَّ اللَّهَ حرَّمَ علَى الأرضِ أن تأكلَ أجسادَ الأنبياءِ
  الراوي:
  أوس بن أبي أوس وقيل أوس بن أوس والد عمرو 
  المحدث: الدارقطني      -   المصدر:  تفسير القرآن  -   الصفحة أو الرقم:  6/463خلاصة حكم المحدث:  [صحيح]

Answer (score 0):

There is a better chain for this hadith which has been classed as Sahih by scholars including [Nawawi](https://shamela.ws/book/2348/1543),  [Ibn Khuzaimah](https://shamela.ws/book/1446/2842), [Ibn Hibban](https://shamela.ws/book/537/577), [Hakim and Dahabi](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/1024), [al-Albani](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1047) and others.

There is also a hint about it in the Quran:

> فلما قضينا عليه الموت ما دلهم على موته إلا دابة الأرض تأكل منسأته فلما خر تبينت الجن أن لو كانوا يعلمون الغيب ما لبثوا في العذاب المهين
>
> And when We decreed for Solomon death, nothing indicated to the jinn his death except a creature of the earth eating his staff. But when he fell, it became clear to the jinn that if they had known the unseen, they would not have remained in humiliating punishment.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 34:14](https://quran.com/34/14?translations=20)</sup>

Which implies that body of Solomon  عليه السلام did not decompose after his death, as the only sign of death that the Jinn observed was that he fell when termites had eaten the staff on which he was leaning.

And there are other sahih reports which corroborate or support its meaning, such as:

> مررت على موسى وهو يصلي في قبره
>
> I passed by Moses when he was praying in his grave
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2375b)</sup>